# Removing PHP logs from the top of webpage

Tags: php, zend-framework

On one of my webpages some logs seem to be pushed out at the top of the page which is causing a rather messy design.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjKvS.png

Any idea how I can stop this from occuring?

Comment: These are php warnings. If it is your own code, you should fix it. If it is not part of your code, you could turn error display off. They should appear in the log as well and on a live site you should not display them anyway.

Comment: It's not my code. How would I go about turning it off?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to edit your php.ini file, set "display_errors" to "Off" like this:

```
display_errors = Off
```

After making this change you will need to restart your web server (eg. Apache) for the change to take effect.

If you don't have access to change your php.ini file, you can add this to your php code:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');
```

If you're having trouble finding your php.ini file, create a small php file containing the following and it will tell you the location of the php.ini file being used:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following statement in your index file.

ini_set("display_errors",0);